# Rmd knit is not generating pdf file

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

I've been trying to generate a pdf file using Rmd. When I click knit I get an error (see picture). I've tried installing tinytex, updating it, closing and opening R and R studio, and nothing has worked so far.[image: Error message]

I've tried to install tinytex, update it, tlmgr update --all

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Did you install TinyTeX? Installing the R package tinytex is not enough. You need a LaTeX distribution, e.g., `tinytex::install_tinytex()`